# tkinter pack_forget not working

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
def addclientWidgets(self):
    self.ename = Entry(self.mainFrame)
    self.ename.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.98, anchor="s", width=150)
    self.ename.insert(0, "Name")

    self.insertButton = Button(self.mainFrame, text="Add", width=10, command=self.addSubmit)
    self.insertButton.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.98, anchor="s")

def addSubmit(self):
    if self.ename.winfo_ismapped():
        self.ename.pack_forget()
```

`pack_forget` isnt working. Is it because I have used `place` instead of `pack`. If so, how do I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes every geometry manager(`pack`, `grid`, `place`) has its own `..._forget` method. Use `place_forget()` instead.